# look behind for this REGEX?

Tags: php, regex

im putting the delimiter i want to split by in caps
just so they will stand out
code should search for upper or lowercase

```
$ReadStr = 'asbhd dbshd ABC/DEF sdjfhjskjhfh hfjhd fkj GHI/JKL sdhjkjhfg';
```

this is what I have...

```
$SplitStr = preg_split("[.../+...]",$ReadStr);

print_r($SplitStr);
```

would output:

```
asbhd dbshd
sdjfhjskjhfh hfjhd fkj
sdhjkjhfg
```

just not sure how to implement the look behind the same exact regex expression...

this is the output i'm looking for:

```
asbhd dbshd 
ABC/DEF sdjfhjskjhfh hfjhd fkj 
GHI/JKL sdhjkjhfg
```

Comment: hmmmm, the code option here works a lot differently than im used to.  Sorry everything got smashed together

Comment: idk why but i couldnt add a comment to Gumbo's answer.  So I will say Thank You Gumbo! here

Answer (score 2):

Use a look-ahead instead:

```
/(?=...\/+...)/
```

Or to be more specific:

```
/(?=[a-z]{3}\/+[a-z]{3})/i
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo! would you be willing to put that in the preg_split function for me?  preg_split(/(?=...\/+...)/,$ReadStr); isnt working

Comment: @SlickRick: You need to quote it properly: `preg_split("/(?=...\\/+...)/",$ReadStr)`